# What is a satisfactory way to typeset ℕ in the Mathematica notebook?

Tags: formatting

I am familiar with typing:

<kbd>esc</kbd>ints<kbd>esc</kbd>

<kbd>esc</kbd>reals<kbd>esc</kbd>

to produce:

[image]

(when typing inside a DisplayFormula cell).

## How would one typeset a similar looking ℕ ?

I have tried `\[DoubleStruckCapitalN]`

but this produces a different looking result:

[image]

(ℕ (an N in "Blackboard Bold" font) is used to refer to the set of all natural numbers.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> you can check that `:reals:` produces `TemplateBox[{}, "Reals"]`. Then you can take a peek at its `DisplayFunction` with:

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Reals"}]
```

> ```
> { TemplateBoxOptionsDisplayFunction -> (StyleBox["\[DoubleStruckCapitalR]", ShowSyntaxStyles -> False, 
>      FontFamily -> "Times"] &), 
>  TemplateBoxOptionsInterpretationFunction -> ("Reals" &), 
>  TemplateBoxOptionsTooltip -> Automatic}
> ```

So the answer to your question is the `FontFamily`:

```
Style["\[DoubleStruckCapitalN]", FontFamily -> "Times"]
```

[image]

---

**Update:**

In addition to that it is worth mentioning `PositiveIntegers`, `NonNegativeIngeters` and all family of combinations of *sign+domain*.

So depending on context you can use `:nnint:` or `:pint:` for natural numbers:

[image]

Those `TemplateBoxes` have additional benefit, they have interpretation so while `Style["\[DoubleStruckCapitalR]", FontFamily -> "Times"]` looks nice, `:reals:` looks nice and represents `Reals` you can use with symbolic math.

Comment: Suggested edit: `:nnints:` and `:pints:` need to be pluralized.

Answer (score 5):

This comes from the pallete.

<kbd>esc</kbd> dsN <kbd>esc</kbd>

You can always **Bold** it with ctrl-b.

Change to Traditional form with ctrl-shift-t to get the same as reals.

Comment: It does not look like `:reals:` and friends.

Comment: Are you on a Mac?  I'm on Windows and they sure look the same to me when they are both either bold or regular.  It really doesn't matter to me what anyone chooses to use.

Comment: I am on Windows 10: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ2PX.png

Comment: Wow.  I don't have have a site to show you, and I don't know what is going on, but except for the last one which isn't bold, they all look identical to your reals.  Its a bracket in front of the R in all cases, not an I with serif.  I enlarged the cell to make sure.  I just figured it out.  Inputform is different, but change to traditional form, it looks like yours.

Comment: Strange, this is what I see with TraditionalForm: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYl4j.png

Comment: Pretty close. I have Traditional form as my standard output form which I guess is the cause of the confusion. its getting close to 3 am my time so I'm done for awhile

Answer (score 5):

## Building on Kuba's solution

Here is code for a shortcut

> <kbd>esc</kbd>nats<kbd>esc</kbd>

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {InputAliases, "nats"}] = StyleBox["\[DoubleStruckCapitalN]", FontFamily -> "Times"];
```

[image]